# Check a CATIA checkbox using macros

Tags: vba, vbscript, catia

In CATIA FTA Workbench, I need to create construction geometry for a particular feature.

In the snapshot below, you can see four circles. I need to create "Circle Center Points" for these circles using the "Construction Geometry Creation" option.

Circles for creating Center Points
[image]

```vb
Language="VBSCRIPT"

Sub CATMain()

Set partDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Set part1 = partDocument1.Part

CATIA.StartCommand "Constructed Geometry Creation"

End Sub
```

It is pretty basic, just using the Start command.

There is a checkbox that pops up.
[image]
I need code to select the option "Point" (which is the only option).

This code is basic, and works only when the circle is selected before running the code, which is not the most productive way to go.
I am trying to build it. I thought if I could make it work for one circle, later I can make it productive.

There is Excel code that accepts checkboxes:

```vb
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.Value=1
```

Is there a similar option for Catia?

Comment: Did you try a SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}") + a sendkeys "enter" ?

Comment: Hi, I had not, but I just did, "Enter" is not checking the checkbox, it is just closing the checkbox. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Then, why don't you use "HybridShapePointCenter" to create center of all your circles after looping on them ? you will not have to interact with a dialog of Catia.

Comment: And sorry, but i've just tried and seems to work : sendkeys "tab" + sendkeys "space key" to uncheck the checkbox, then to leave your dialog sendkeys "enter".

It would work. To use sendkeys "space key", try to use : SendKeys(" ")